# Manage Threads on Rxjava

Tags: android, multithreading, redux, rx-java, state-management

I am trying to implement the Redux pattern to manage state following the presentation by Jake Wharton: http://jakewharton.com/the-state-of-managing-state-with-rxjava/
I want everything in the stream to run on a background thread and receive the output on the AndroidMainThread. But with this current set up, my Subscriber throws an exception that i am manipulating the UI on another thread other than the AndroidMainThread. Thanks in advance.

```
Observable events = Observable.merge(Observable.just(new GetUsersEvent()/*, other event streams*/));
        events.compose(mergeEvents(GetUsersEvent.class, /* other events */))
                .compose(events -> events.map(event -> {
                    BaseAction action = null;
                    if (event instanceof GetUsersEvent)
                        action = new GetUsersAction();
                    return action;
                })
                        .compose(actions -> actions.flatMap(action -> Observable.just(action)
                                .flatMap(action -> {
                                    Observable result = Observable.empty();
                                    if (action instanceof GetUsersAction)
                                        result = userListVM.getUsers()
                                                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper())); // I am using a handler thread to receive live updates from realm
                                    return result;
                                })
                                .map(Result::successResult)
                                .onErrorReturn(Result::errorResult)
                                .startWith(Result.IN_FLIGHT)))
                        .scan(initialState, (currentUIModel, result) -> {
                            if (result.isLoading())
                                currentUIModel = UIModel.loadingState(bundle);
                            else if (result.isSuccessful())
                                currentUIModel = UIModel.successState(result);
                            else currentUIModel = UIModel.errorState(result.getError());
                            return currentUIModel;
                        })
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
                .subscribe(o -> {/* update UI */}, OnErrorNotImplementedException::new);
```

mergeEvents transformer:

```
public Observable.Transformer<BaseEvent, BaseEvent> mergeEvents(Class... classes) {
        return events -> events.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .publish(shared -> {
                    List<Class> classList = Arrays.asList(classes);
                    for (int i = 0, size = classList.size(); i < size; i++)
                        shared = shared.mergeWith(shared.ofType(classList.get(i)));
                    return shared;
                });
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
    at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:112)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Expected to be called on the main thread but was RxIoScheduler-2
       at com.zeyad.usecases.app.components.mvvm.BaseSubscriber.onError(BaseSubscriber.java:36)
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:153)
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:115)
       at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onError(SerializedObserver.java:152)
       at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:78)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTakeUntil$1.onError(OperatorTakeUntil.java:50)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:273)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216)
       at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:107)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to be called on the main thread but was RxIoScheduler-2
       at rx.android.MainThreadSubscription.verifyMainThread(MainThreadSubscription.java:58)
       at com.jakewharton.rxbinding.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewScrollEventOnSubscribe.call(RecyclerViewScrollEventOnSubscribe.java:19)
       at com.jakewharton.rxbinding.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewScrollEventOnSubscribe.call(RecyclerViewScrollEventOnSubscribe.java:10)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter.call(OnSubscribeFilter.java:45)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter.call(OnSubscribeFilter.java:30)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:248)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:148)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray$FromArrayProducer.fastPath(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:76)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray$FromArrayProducer.request(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:58)
       at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray.call(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:32)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray.call(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:24)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscr
```

Comment: Do you have a Stacktrace? Could it be that one operator in the chain tries to modify some UI-State? I do not see any UI-value-changes and the observeOn Android.mainThread should switch the thread to UI right before accessing the UI via subscribe. What does scheduleOn do?

Comment: I added the stack trace, it wasnt that much of help for me. Non of the operators touch UI elements, only in the subscriber. I fixed the type in the scheduleOn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want everything in the stream to run on a background thread and receive the output on the AndroidMainThread

You can't have everything in the stream at background thread, because your'e source of events are UI events that must be registered at main thread.

You're applying IO Scheduler at `mergeEvents` transformer, that'e means that all of your UI events will be subscribed at IO thread.

You can see the source at the log:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to be called on the main thread but was RxIoScheduler-2
   at rx.android.MainThreadSubscription.verifyMainThread(MainThreadSubscription.java:58)
   at com.jakewharton.rxbinding.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewScrollEventOnSubscribe.call(RecyclerViewScrollEventOnSubscribe.java:19)
   at com.jakewharton.rxbinding.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewScrollEventOnSubscribe.call(RecyclerViewScrollEventOnSubscribe.java:10)
```

You are trying to subscribe to RecyclerView scroll events not at the main thread.
You can fix it simply by subscribing at `mergeEvents` at mainThread, and then put `observeOn` at some bg thread of your choice, so the rest of the stream will be handled off the UI thread.